# Capture single SQL Select statement

Tags: sql-server

Hello SQL coders and Gurus

I’ve been coding SQL for a few years now and I’ve always wondered how you can grab the first SQL statement a user executes against the DB each day say.
The user might have a number of Select statements highlighted when they hit F5 (to execute one after another) but I’m just trying to get the first one.

I’ve got a couple of my efforts to do this below but they return too much please see.

### EXAMPLE A  . ..

---

```
SELECT 'blah from first select' 
SELECT 'blah from second select' 

DECLARE @sqltext VARBINARY(128)
SELECT @sqltext = sql_handle
FROM sys.sysprocesses
WHERE spid = @@SPID
SELECT  TEXT 
FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(@sqltext)
```

### ----------------------------------------------

Which when executed returns all of this  . ..

```
‘SELECT 'blah from first select' 
 SELECT 'blah from second select' 

DECLARE @sqltext VARBINARY(128)
SELECT @sqltext = sql_handle
FROM sys.sysprocesses
WHERE spid = @@SPID
SELECT  TEXT 
FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(@sqltext)’
```

But the result I want is just the first select statement executed by the DB.. ..
‘SELECT 'blah from first select'‘

There may be many long and complex select statements run (in the batch) but I need only the first full SQL statement string executed.

--================================================

### EXAMPLE B . ..

---

```
SELECT 'blah from first select' 
SELECT 'blah from second select' 

SELECT execquery.last_execution_time AS [Date Time], execsql.text AS [Script] FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS execquery
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(execquery.sql_handle) AS execsql
--  where execsql.text like '%MHD%'
ORDER BY execquery.last_execution_time DESC
```

### ------------------------------------------------

This statement returns a number of lines but even taking the first you still get . ..

```
‘SELECT 'blah from first select' 
 SELECT 'blah from second select' 

SELECT execquery.last_execution_time AS [Date Time], execsql.text AS [Script] FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS execquery
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(execquery.sql_handle) AS execsql
--  where execsql.text like '%MHD%'
ORDER BY execquery.last_execution_time DESC’
```

And again the result I really want is . ..
‘SELECT 'blah from first select'

Can anyone please help ??
I hope I’ve explained myself well and that someone may help and hopefully have fun with this little puzzle.

Cheers nosinet

Comment: Aside from the obvious question as to why you wish to do this, the problem remains that the result of `dm_exec_sql_text` is actually correct because it is giving you the last batch executed.  Separating your statements with `GO`, will break them into separate batches but you will only receive the final statement executed.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  Have you considered a SQL or Extended Event Trace?  If you capture the SQL:BatchStarting and SQL:StmtStarting events, a query against the traced data can find the first SQL:StmtStarting event after the SQL:BatchStarting event by SPID.

Comment: g'day @MartinParkin. .. hey thanks for your answer . ..   see I cant separate them with GO because I'm not writing them. I was hoping the DB management system would separate them and identify them before they were run . .. Im mean they are run in order aren't they ??

Comment: g'day  @DanGuzman . .. Im using 2012 express ...  hey that sound interesting thanQ. So I should look into SQL:BatchStarting or Extended Event Trace first ??   chuz

Comment: @nosinet, SQL Trace is deprecated so it would be best to use XE.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of an XE trace:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [FirstStatementTrace] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sp_statement_starting(
    ACTION(package0.collect_system_time,package0.event_sequence,sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.username)),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_batch_starting(
    ACTION(package0.collect_system_time,package0.event_sequence,sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.username)) 
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'FirstStatementTrace')
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=OFF)
GO

ALTER EVENT SESSION [FirstStatementTrace] ON SERVER STATE = START;
GO
```

And here's an example of how you could extract the information from the trace data.  There is much room for improvement from a performance perspective but I don't have time to tweak it right now.  This should get you started, though.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#shredded_event_data', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #shredded_event_data;
GO

WITH 
    event_data AS (
        SELECT
            object_name, CAST(event_data AS xml) AS event_data_xml
        FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file ( N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log\FirstStatementTrace*.xel', NULL, DEFAULT, DEFAULT )
    )
    , shredded_event_data AS (
        SELECT 
              object_name
            , event_data_xml.value('/event[1]/action[@name="collect_system_time"][1]/value[1]', 'datetime2(3)') AS collect_system_time
            , event_data_xml.value('/event[1]/action[@name="event_sequence"][1]/value[1]', 'bigint') AS event_sequence
            , event_data_xml.value('/event[1]/action[@name="client_app_name"][1]/value[1]', 'sysname') AS client_app_name
            , event_data_xml.value('/event[1]/action[@name="client_hostname"][1]/value[1]', 'sysname') AS client_hostname
            , event_data_xml.value('/event[1]/action[@name="session_id"][1]/value[1]', 'smallint') AS session_id
            , event_data_xml.value('/event[1]/action[@name="sql_text"][1]/value[1]', 'nvarchar(MAX)') AS sql_text
        FROM event_data
    )
SELECT
      collect_system_time
    , event_sequence
    , client_app_name
    , client_hostname
    , session_id
    , sql_text
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY session_id ORDER BY event_sequence) AS row_num
INTO #shredded_event_data
FROM shredded_event_data;
```

Comment: Hey Dan this is phenomenal. I'll have a crack and let you kno . ..  thanks a million !  Happy Days